# show Loader or busyindicator while naviagting from one page to other page using Router is not working

Tags: sapui5

I am using below snippet for navigating pages with dynamic menu and I need to show the loader or BusyIndicator while navigating from one page to other pages.

```
var oBusyDialog_Global = new sap.m.BusyDialog("GlobalBusyDialog",{title:"Please wait. . . "});
```

Code in `createContent()` method:

```
this.addEventDelegate({  
  onBeforeShow: function(event) {  
      var getDialog = sap.ui.getCore().byId("GlobalBusyDialog");  
      getDialog.open();  
  }  
}, this);
```

But I am not able to see the BusyDialog. It raises an error like

> Cannot read property 'BusyDialog' of undefined.

Please help in solving this issue.

Comment: If it cannot find `BusyDialog`, sounds like you're not pulling in the `sap.m` library. Can you post your full code on jsbin.com? Make sure in your index.html the SAPUI5 bootstrapper data-sap-ui-libs attribute has "sap.m" in it. You can comma separate libraries in this attribute.

Comment: A new dialog popup will be open when click the button,I need to show the loader between this